# How to get Google Plus's post data ( likes - shares - comments )?

Tags: c#, .net, api, c#-4.0, google-plus

Using C# , I want to read the **Shares , Comments and Likes** of a Google + post like this https://plus.google.com/107200121064812799857/posts/GkyGQPLi6KD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That post is an activity. [This page](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/get) includes infomation on how to get infomation about activities. [This page](https://developers.google.com/+/api/) gives some examples of using the API. [This page](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/APIs#Google+_API) has downloads for the Google API .NET library, which you can use to access the Google+ APIs, with XML documentation etc.

You'll need to use the [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) to get an API key and manage your API usage.

Also take a look at the [API Explorer](http://code.google.com/apis/explorer/#_s=plus&_v=v1&_m=activities.get).

Here's a working example:

---

Referencing Google.Apis.dll and Google.Apis.Plus.v1.dll

```
        PlusService plus = new PlusService();
        plus.Key = "YOURAPIKEYGOESHERE";
        ActivitiesResource ar = new ActivitiesResource(plus);
        ActivitiesResource.Collection collection = new ActivitiesResource.Collection();

        //107... is the poster's id
        ActivitiesResource.ListRequest list = ar.List("107200121064812799857", collection); 
        ActivityFeed feed = list.Fetch();

        //You'll obviously want to use a _much_ better way to get
        // the activity id, but you aren't normally searching for a
        // specific URL like this.
        string activityKey = "";
        foreach (var a in feed.Items)
            if (a.Url == "https://plus.google.com/107200121064812799857/posts/GkyGQPLi6KD")
            {
                activityKey = a.Id;
                break;
            }

        ActivitiesResource.GetRequest get = ar.Get(activityKey);
        Activity act = get.Fetch();
        Console.WriteLine("Title: "+act.Title);
        Console.WriteLine("URL:"+act.Url);
        Console.WriteLine("Published:"+act.Published);
        Console.WriteLine("By:"+act.Actor.DisplayName);
        Console.WriteLine("Annotation:"+act.Annotation);
        Console.WriteLine("Content:"+act.Object.Content);
        Console.WriteLine("Type:"+act.Object.ObjectType);
        Console.WriteLine("# of +1s:"+act.Object.Plusoners.TotalItems);
        Console.WriteLine("# of reshares:"+act.Object.Resharers.TotalItems);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Output:

```
    Title: Wow Awesome creativity...!!!!!
    URL:http://plus.google.com/107200121064812799857/posts/GkyGQPLi6KD
    Published:2012-04-07T05:11:22.000Z
    By:Funny Pictures & Videos
    Annotation:
    Content: Wow Awesome creativity...!!!!!
    Type:note
    # of +1s:210
    # of reshares:158
```

Comment: if we have this post ( activity ) https://plus.google.com/114277819599398268182/posts/eoNrpWWF9KY What's activity ID ?  as i tried " eoNrpWWF9KY  " but it give me : "Unable to find activity with ID: eoNrpWWF9KY "

Comment: ActivityFeed contains all the activities from a user. You can iterate through ActivityFeed.Items to find one that meets some requirement and then use it's ID. In this case you one asked for a specific URL, so I used that. The ID for this one was "z13qd5zouuebcpauy23tuftwdsylxflvs". For eoNrpWWF9KY it's "z12tsvgjwyvawtzr104cixjqrsm1j5pxjyk0k".

Comment: @ Kiran Price - can you please tell  me how to get activity id for an post